# Remove query string (?page=login) using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove query string but it's not working this code I generated from https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator and I really can't find it wrong anywhere but it's not working please help me

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page\=login$
RewriteRule ^$ /login? [L]
```

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page\=login$
RewriteRule ^$ /login? [L]

php_flag display_errors 1
```

Comment: What is the full URL? The rule you posted would only remove the query string from the “homepage”.

Comment: @MrWhite ???.???/?page=login

Comment: Is `???.???` meant to be the hostname? And by “not working” you mean it’s not doing anything? No error? Is your .htaccess file doing anything? (Are .htaccess overrides enabled on your server?)

Comment: @MrWhite It's show 404 error

Comment: You appear to be trying to do more than just "remove the query string", you are also redirecting to the URL-path `/login`? Is that intentional? Is `/login` a valid URL in your application? How is `/login` routed in your application? There is nothing that you've shown that would do this?

Comment: I want change ???.???/?page=login to ???.???/login

Comment: Ok, but that's very different to what you are asking in the question. Are you using PHP? WHat is the actual file that handles the request? `index.php`?

Comment: I found the answer I needed through an online source code, thanks for your time

Comment: I have already written an answer - please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ /login? [L]
> ```

This is an internal rewrite, not a redirect. To issue an external redirect and  actually *remove* the query string from the request then you need the `R` (`redirect`) flag.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /login? [R=302,L]
```

However, this does not simply remove the query string, it also redirects to the URL-path `/login`. (And there's nothing in your `.htaccess` file that would allow this to work.) To simply *remove* the query string, as stated in your question then you need to remove `login` from the *substitution* string. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=302,L]
```

If this is intended to be permanent then change to a 301, but only once you have confirmed that it works as intended.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I want change `???.???/?page=login` to `???.???/login`

Ok, but that is quite different to what your question is asking.

Make sure you are already linking to `/login` in your application then add the following to your `.htaccess` file, replacing the existing rule:

```
# Redirect old requests for the query string
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/\?page=login\s
RewriteRule ^$ /login [QSD,R=301,L]

# Rewrite requests for "/login" to actual URL that handles the request
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?page=login [L]
```

Assuming `index.php` is the actual end-point (file) that handles the request.